# Setting alias name for the gridview field

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

My table having a field `fld_status`. It hold the values 0 and 1. `0` means active ,`1` means inactive. But i want to show the meaning full name like active for `0` in the Gridview. Is there is any way to change this value 0 and 1 meaningful name in `Gridview` other than query?

```
 <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="40px" HeaderText="STATUS">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_status" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Fld_status")%>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemStyle Width="40px"></ItemStyle>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
```

In gridview STATUS column show 0 and 1. I want to show only active and inactive based on o and 1.

Comment: Show your aspx of the GridView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a `TemplateField`:

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="40px" HeaderText="STATUS">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lbl_status" runat="server" 
            Text='<%# (Eval("Fld_status")==1) ? "active" : "inactive" %>'>
        </asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemStyle Width="40px"></ItemStyle>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

or from the GridView's `RowDataBound`:

```
protected void gridview1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DataRow row = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
        bool isActive = row.Field<int>("Fld_status") == 1;
        Label lbl_status = (Label) e.Row.FindControl("lbl_status");
        lbl_status.Text = isActive ? "active" : "inactive"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Do we need `.ToString()`? Can't it be like `<%# Eval("Fld_status") ? "active" : "inactive" %>` ?

Comment: @Kaf: Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: +1 you deserve for hard work. more that what user expected. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use in `ItemTepmlate`.

```
<ItemTemplate><%# Eval("Fld_status") ? "active" : "inactive" %></ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: I think it can be like `<%# Eval("Fld_status") ? "active" : "inactive" %>` ? isn't it?